# Destroy Session when User Closed browser and also from session table

Tags: php, session, yii2

I want to destroy session when I close browser in yii2, for that I used that code in web,config file:-

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\TblUser',

        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'loginUrl' => ['site/index/login'],
     ],
```

With the help of this code I am successfully destroyed session but at that time session table not updated. When manually I log-out user that time session table updated. Please help me when I will close browser, that time my session table also be update.

Thank you

Comment: 'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\TblUser',

        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'loginUrl' => ['site/index/login'],
         'authTimeout' => 1800

     ],

Comment: @Gulshan with the help of this code you can only destroy session not update session table in database

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

You can only tell the user's browser to discard the session *cookie* as soon as the browser is closed. Or in more technically correct terms - the browser is being told that it shouldn't permanently store that cookie.

But there's no way for the *server* to know if/when a browser is closed.

A mechanism called "garbage collection" should clear-up those old session records from your database later. It just periodically checks for expired session data and deletes it.